# NPM Install won't use my provided git url

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a dev dependancy in my package.json file that points to a local gitlab repository.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^1.2.1",
    "event-stream": "^3.1.5",
...
    "mymodule": "git+http://my.gitlab.url/team/repo.git",
...
    "run-sequence": "^0.3.6"
  }
```

This does not work. When I look in the npm-debug.log file, it seems that instead of cloning the repo from gitlab, its trying to find it in the npm repository:

```
26 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mymodule
27 http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/mymodule
```

Then of course further down in the file:

```
32 error 404 404 Not Found: mymodule
32 error 404
32 error 404 'mymodule' is not in the npm registry.
32 error 404 You should bug the author to publish it
```

If i run git clone to get the contents of the repo it works. If I run "npm install" followed by the path in the package.json file it works. But it does not work when I run a simple "npm install".

Can anyone explain why?

So..... why does it not honour the gitlab path in my package.json when I run "npm install"?

Comment: Did you try: "mymodule": "git://my.gitlab.url/team/repo.git" ?

Comment: Yup - also doesn't work:54 error fatal: unable to connect to my.gitlab.url:
54 error my.gitlab.url[0: 10.1.5.97]: errno=No such file or directory

Comment: Your Git lab doesn't need a specified user ? `git+http://user@my.gitlab.url/team/repo.git`

Comment: Nope - it's a public repo. I can clone it by simply running git clone http://my.gitlab.url/team/repo.git

Comment: P.S. I have also tried with a username and password - same result. I have also tried adding #master onto the end of the URL. Same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages are a red herring. This was caused by app level inspection (and blocking) on our firewall. Answer here as a "something to check with your security guys" for the next person.